# Please help to identify this insect

Tags: species-identification, entomology

It is approx 1.5 inch (3 cm to 4.5 cm) long

[image: The insect]

The insect's back and wings.

[image: Insect from its front]

Insect from its forward side

Just few hours ago (around night 10 to 10.30 pm local time), this insect entered into our home, flying in high-speed and hitting to wall, objects, and to us. To keep it calm we turned the room-light off. Then it became steady on my father's shirt even after the light again turned on, and it was a beautiful moth-like insect. After taking photo it gently freed out of the room.

Here in India, it is rainy season (after summer).

---

P.S. I've very very little-experience in practical-zoology, however after few hours google search it seems to match with those moths tagged as "hawk-moths", and another notable feature when it was flying it looked like a hummingbird or a small bird, that was written in the description of some "hawk-moths" in different sites. Initially we're taking time to decide whether it is an insect or a bird.

Comment: What part of India are you in?

Comment: @MattDMo West Bengal. Kolkata.

Comment: It looks like http://static.inaturalist.org/photos/330773/medium.jpg?1444601918 http://rainforest-australia.com/Hawk%20Moth%20w.jpg,  ; http://www.whatsthatbug.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/vine_hawkmoth_hawaii_gini.jpg, http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2655/4241673563_da597de6fa.jpg, and https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8349/8223004042_a23ffc8029.jpg. etc.

Comment: If I able to identify it by someone, I'll upload it here. Thanks.

Comment: Related one, from same country : http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/50432/a-new-species-of-small-bird

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As `MattDMo` suggested, this is a hawk moth.  Given your location and season, this is why I thought it was either the Impatiens hawkmoth (*Theretra oldenlandiae*) or the  White-edged hunter hawkmoth (*Theretra lycetus*).  And finally, why I now think it is the Brown-Banded Hunter (*Theretra silhetensis*).

## Brown-Banded Hunter Hawkmoth

The [*Theretra silhetensis*](http://www.inaturalist.org/taxa/121856-Theretra-silhetensis) exhibits a solid white line along the upperside of its abdomen, and more of a faded banding pattern on the forethat corresponds with your picture.  These moths are also [common in India](http://tpittaway.tripod.com/china/t_sil.htm).

> It is differs from *T. oldenlandiae* in being very much paler in color
> and with white line down center of abdomen.

[image]

When it comes down to it, that solid single white line is the biggest indicator it is a *T. silhetensis* over a *T. oldenlandiae* or *T. lycetus*.

---

While my final answer is the brown-banded hunter hawkmoth, below are the original two species I suspected it was and why.  I've included them below simply for reference / alternative comparisons.

## Impatiens Hawkmoth

[*Theretra oldenlandiae*](http://www.inaturalist.org/taxa/125110-Theretra-oldenlandiae) was my original instinct, since it is a more common in your area and the banding/stripe pattern matches to a T.

[image]

But, upon closer inspection, there are two things that don't quite align:

- Your Specimen exhibits pink suffusion, especially on the back edge of the fore wing.
- Your specimen has a single dorsal line, not two.

For these two reasons I think it is not the Impatiens Hawkmoth and thought it was more likely the...

## White-edged hunter hawkmoth

[*Theretra lycetus*](http://www.inaturalist.org/taxa/498837) is not as common on the *T. oldenlandiae* for your location, but the pink suffusion supports this idea.  See below for a picture:

[image]

This still doesn't explain the double vs. single white stripe along the upper abdomen.  Which is why I know believe it is the...

---

As an aside, this could be an example of polymorphism vs. identifying characters. Welcome to the world of taxonomic lumpers and splitters...

Comment: I agree with your eventual answer, but do you think you could put your final answer a bit nearer the top? :)

Comment: Fair enough...Now edited to save reading time.

Comment: Thanks. Also I don't  know, how-frequent posting of identification question is considered as OK, (i.e. is there any limit on it) in this SE community, however I posted this-one because this-insect was very surprising to us... it looked like a tiny bird when it was flying.

Comment: First-one (*Theretra silhetensis*) shows excellent matching

Comment: No problem at all.  I think as long as you do not spam posts you should be in the clear (although I'm not the final say in the matter).  As for confusing a moth for a bird, you aren't the first one! [This moth in the same _Sphingidae_ family](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/50432/a-new-species-of-small-bird/50433#50433) was posted just last week!  And thank you to your post!  Very clear picture of the moth with a good explanation

Answer (score 2):

This is almost certainly a Hawkmoth in the family [*Sphingidae*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphingidae), possibly (I am in no way, shape, or form an entomologist) an example of [*Therectra alecto*](http://tpittaway.tripod.com/sphinx/t_ale.htm), known as the Levant Hawkmoth:

[image]

[This page](http://www.whatsthatbug.com/2015/11/01/possibly-levant-hawkmoth-from-india/) gave me the clue, and the link to the page above. Like I said, I'm not an entomologist :)

Comment: probably this one you're telling about http://www.whatsthatbug.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/hawkmoth_india_arjun-300x290.jpg. However our-one contains very bold  long mark on back. However like our-one, yours also contain the black dot on 2 wings.

Comment: Almost positive it's the Impatiens hawkmoth, (_Theretra oldenlandiae_), which is common in India.  [Site for reference](http://www.inaturalist.org/taxa/125110-Theretra-oldenlandiae)

Comment: @DGruenewald I think you're right. Go ahead and write up an answer.