# What is this hummingbird-like insect?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I just saw this insect collecting polen from bougainvillea blossoms on the Greek island of Skyros, in the Aegean sea. For future reference, this is in the middle of August and the sighting was at around 17:00.

[image: a photo of the insect in question]

[image: a photo of the insect in question]

[image: a photo of the insect in question]

[image: a photo of the insect in question]

I posted all 4 photos I took since the rude little thing didn't have the decency to sit still to let me get a clear shot. I'd say it was about 2cm long, certainly no more than 3.

Comment: Had you asked this earlier, you would have gotten 40 points: http://biology.stackexchange.com/q/50432/3340

Comment: @WYSIWYG aww, dang! :P May as well close as a dupe then.

Comment: Related one: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/50592/please-help-to-identify-this-insect

Answer (score 2):

[Hummingbird hawk-moth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hummingbird_hawk-moth) (*Macroglossum stellatarum*). For what it's worth, there are also a variety of [sphinx moths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphingidae) around the world.

Here's a photo from the linked Wikipedia page. As you can see, it looks very much like the one in yours:

[image]